# Python GTK 3 Table: Buttons should not expand

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3

Using following code, I have the problems, that the buttons "Log Leeren" and "Auto Scroll" change their height, when I resize the window. They should be exactly one text-line high and the rest of the viewport should be used by the scrolledWindow

What do I need to change:

```
class ConsoleLogWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, server):
        self.log = server["log"];
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Meteor Log von %s" % server["name"])

        # self.set_icon_from_file("filename")

        self.set_size_request(800,500)

        table = Gtk.Table(3, 2, False)

        self.add(table)

        # Should be only one line of thext high
        self.button_clear = Gtk.Button(label="Log Leeren")
        self.button_scroll = Gtk.Button(label="Auto Scroll")

        table.attach(self.button_clear, 2, 3, 1, 2)
        table.attach(self.button_scroll, 0, 1, 1, 2)

        # should take as much space as is available.
        scrollWindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrollWindow.set_hexpand(False)
        scrollWindow.set_vexpand(True)

        self.content_table = Gtk.Table(len(self.log)+1, 4, False)
        # self.content_table is filled here.

        scrollWindow.add(self.content_table)

        table.attach(scrollWindow, 0, 3, 0, 1)
```

the window class is called in a function like:

```
def show_errors_menu(self, widget):
    print ("Showing Error Menu")
    win = ConsoleLogWindow(widget.get_node());
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `Gtk.Table`; it does not always respect the `expand` and `align` properties of its child widgets. Its replacement since GTK 3.0 has been `Gtk.Grid`. Using that, you only have to make sure that `expand` is set to true on the scrolled window and false on the buttons.

Comment: this solves my initial problem with the vertical expansion of the buttons but now I have the complete grid only 2 buttons wide.

Answer (score 0):

In the Qt side, at least, the frameworks consider for every widget a `size` attribute, a `minimumSize` attribute and a `maximumSize` attribute. Setting these three attributes to the same value for height and width makes them unresizable. Java's widgets have a explicit `resizable` attribute. I don't know how GTK3 prevents resizing, but doing some web search I came across [this recipe](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074784) which makes unresizable windows by extending and adding `self.set_resizable(False)` which is said to work. Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: I do not want to disable the resizing of the window, I want to disable the resizing of the buttons when I resize the window, that my scrollable area (In GTK 3 called ScrolledWindow) takes as much space as available.

Comment: I understood you wanted to freeze the size of buttons, so my suggestion was to apply the same technique done in the recipe I sent to you to a button (that is, create a subclass of the GTK's button and add the property `self.set_resizable(False)`. *(Sorry if I hadn't explained myself clear) :/* Try it and let me know! :D